# Why is each iteration not being pushed as a row within sheets by Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-apps-script

I'm learning Google Apps Script and am running some example code to help me understand how code is being interpreted. I'm sorry if these are very basic question but I'm trying to understand two things from the below code:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet_url).getSheetByName(sheet_name);

for (var i=0;i<5;i++){
var text = "The number is " + i;

var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1+i,1);

sheet.clear();

range.setValue(text);

console.log(text);
 }
}
```

1. why the logger is returning each value whilst i iterates but the complete range in the Google sheet is being populated with "The number is 4" (i.e. the final iteration). I want each iteration to be posted into the sheet to replicate what's seen in the logger.
2. why range.setValue(text); allows the output to be set to the range but range.setValues(text); returns an error. Am I right in assuming this is because the output is being seen as a single value despite it being sent to multiple cells - i.e. the set function looks at the number of values being sent rather than the number of places the value is being sent to?

Again, apologies for the basic nature of my question. I am reading books and trying to work through practical examples. Any feedback is much appreciated.

Thanks
Nicky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myfunc() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(sheet_url).getSheetByName(sheet_name);
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var text = "The number is " + i;
    sheet.getRange(i+1,1).setValue(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you very much for this answer. It worked perfectly. Are you able to explain to me why the change in range had such a profound impact on the output? Would I be right in saying you changed the range from 2 dimensional to 1 dimensional? Thank you

Comment: You were increment the number of rows not the row.  If you're only writing to one cell you only need the first two parameters which are row and column

Comment: Thank you very much Cooper